# Getting data from checkbox into laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5, laravel-8

This seems so simple. But has me stumped...
I have a table with some records and one cell has a bootstrap custom-switch input in it.
The switches are rendering correctly. But i cannot get the array back into my controller.

**Blade View**

```
<form action="{{ route('Admin.Livestatus.Update', $prop, ['prop' => $prop->id]) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input  type="checkbox" 
                class="custom-control-input" 
                id="sitelive" 
                name="sitelive[]" 
                value="{{ $prop->sitelive }}" 
                onchange="javascript:this.form.submit()" 
                @if($prop->sitelive == 1) checked @endif>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="sitelive"></label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
class AdminLiveOnSiteController extends Controller
{    
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $prop = Properties::findorFail($id);    
        $validated = $request->validate(['sitelive' => 'required']);
        $prop->sitelive = $validated['sitelive'];        
        $prop->save();

        $request->session()->flash('alert-class', 'alert-success');
        $request->session()->flash('message', 'Live status updated!');

        return redirect()->route('Admin.Admin',  [ 'Property', 'All' ]);            
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and suspect that the issue is happening when you uncheck the box.  HTML does not submit empty checkboxes in the POST request.  Therefore, there is nothing to validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers....
I've just figured out what i'd done wrong and it was a combination of not understanding how checkboxes work (not returning data when empty). That the value is what is sent when the box is checked, also my understanding of linking the label and the form element. Also unnecessarily had validation (which would have failed) in the controller... Basically everything!

Still hope this might help someone in a similar situation

**Blade**

```
<form action="{{ route('Admin.Livestatus.Update', $prop, ['prop' => $prop->id]) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')

    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" 
               name="sitelive" 
               class="custom-control-input" 
               onchange="javascript:this.form.submit()" 
               id="{{$prop->id}}" 
               value="1" 
               @if($prop->sitelive === 1) checked @endif>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{$prop->id}}"></label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $prop = Properties::findorFail($id);
    $prop->sitelive = $request->sitelive;    
    $prop->save();

    return redirect()->route('Admin.Admin',  [ 'Property', 'All' ]);
}
```

So basically, if the toggle is selected. Then the DB record is set to one. Else its set to null, as nothing was returned..

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example this might help
[image]

This is one from one of my projects while i was testing, in this on column client needed for updating status(Active/Inactive) of each user one by one.

Here is the html part

```
'<div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-control-success custom-control-lg mb-2">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input isUserActive" data-url="'.route('admin.users.updateUserStatus').'" data-user-id="'.$user->id.'" id="example-sw-custom-success-'.$user->id.'" name="is_active[]" value="'.$user->is_active.'" '.($user->is_active === 'active' ? 'checked="checked"' : ' ').'>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="example-sw-custom-success-'.$user->id.'"></label>
</div>'
```

This is the string which is rendered after fully loading datatables i am using this package for datatables in laravel for rendering datatables.

```
"yajra/laravel-datatables": "^1.5"
```

About handling bootstrap-switch
**Laravel controller**

```
   /**
     * Update User Status
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function updateUserStatus(Request $request){
        try{
            User::where('id',$request->get('user_id'))->update([
               'is_active'  => $request->get('status')
            ]);
            if($request->get('status') === 'active'){
                $getUserData = User::where('id',$request->get('user_id'))->first();
                Mail::to($getUserData)->send(new UserActiveRegistration($getUserData));
            }
            return response()->json([
                'status'    => 'success',
                'message'   => 'User Status Updated successfully.'
            ]);
        }catch (Exception $exception){
            return response()->json([
                'status'    => 'error',
                'message'   => $exception->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Jquery Part

```
/*
* User Status Update
*/
if($('.isUserActive').val() === 'active'){
    $('.isUserActive').attr('checked','checked').toggle("click");
}else{
    $('.isUserActive').removeAttr('checked');
}
$(document).on('change','.isUserActive',function () {
    if($(this).val() === 'active'){
        $(this).val('inactive');
    }else{
        $(this).val('active');
    }
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You want to update the status of the user ?",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, update it!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            let table = $('#dataTables').DataTable();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
                data: {
                    user_id     : $(this).attr('data-user-id'),
                    status      : $(this).val(),
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Updated!',
                        '',
                        'success'
                    )
                    table.ajax.reload();
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is just another way of handling bootstrap-switch in the table.

I hope this will be helpful.